# Can Core Bluetooth connections be long lived?

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth

I have a Mac app acting as as central and an iOS app acting as as peripheral. They are both using Core Bluetooth to communicate. **How long can I expect the connection to live? Can connections be long lived?**

I find that the iOS peripheral disconnects quickly after some inactivity (maybe 10-15 seconds) and I have to keep reconnecting to send more data over.

The error I get on disconnection is "Code=6 “The connection has timed out unexpectedly.” (happens all the time on an iOS device running iOS 10 and a newer one running iOS 14).

The error message make it sound like this shouldn't happen, but maybe that's how BLE is supposed to work and I shouldn't expect to use it more like a web socket.

Comment: The connection should be stable, unless you have radio issues such as interference or the firmware can't schedule radio time for your connection. The error code 6 means the Bluetooth controller firmware lost the connection, and is not a software issue on the host side (i.e. in the OS).

Comment: @Emil I've noticed that if I send something at some interval (e.g. 1 second), the peripheral never disconnects. Is it common to have to implement this kind of heartbeat signal?

Comment: It might affect the scheduler in a way that you suddenly don't see the problem anymore if you're lucky. But in BLE communication, the master already pings the slave once per connection interval, so this should not be needed.